# Открыть одним кликом несколько ссылок в yii2 GridView::widget

Tags: php, yii2

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => CheckboxColumn::class
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'id',
                'value' => function (Advert $model) {
                    return Html::a($model->id, $model->source);
            },
                'format' => 'raw'
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'photos_number',
                'label' => 'Картинка',
                'value' => function (Advert $model) {
                    if (!empty($model->photos)) {
                        return Image::img($model->photos[0], ['hp' => 150, 'wl' => 150, 'far' => 'C', 'bg' => 'ffffff']);
                    }
                    return null;
                },
                'format' => 'raw'
            ],
 ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',],
        ],
```

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался. Выбранные в гриде Checkbox нужно открыть в новой вкладке по одному клику, к примеру по кнопке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно назначить чекбоксу класс и передать в его data ссылку, на которую нужно перейти. По нажатию кнопки открывать ссылки в отдельных окнах.

```
[
    'class' => \yii\grid\CheckboxColumn::class,
    'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return ['class' => 'checkboxClass', 'data-target' => $model->source];
    }
]
```

Если используешь jQuery:

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(e) {
    $(input.checkboxClass:checked).each(function(index, item){
        window.open($(item).data('target'));
    });
});
```